# HUSKY_SKIP_HOOKS=1 ignored during rebase

Tags: rebase, husky

I'm trying to rebase, but the Husky hooks keep running between commits even after
`HUSKY_SKIP_HOOKS=1 git rebase ...`, failing the rebasing process.
`git rebase --no-verify` did not help either.
How to resolve this?

Comment: It hasn't been `HUSKY_SKIP_HOOKS` [since v4](https://typicode.github.io/husky/migrate-from-v4.html). Current behaviour [is documented](https://typicode.github.io/husky/how-to.html#skipping-git-hooks).

Answer (score 0):

Use `HUSKY=0 git rebase ...` instead, see
[this comment](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/487#issuecomment-1603921959).